# Not all elements are displayed on smaller screens

Tags: android, android-layout, android-screen-support

I have a linear layout with some EditText and Buttons. And when running the app on smaller screens, the layout gets cut off (not all elements are displayed). I've added `<supports-screens ...>` in manifest, but it's still not working. Is there a way to display all elements?

**Edit: Code:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:text="@string/tx" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/tx1"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="@string/ed1"
    android:inputType="number" >

    <requestFocus />
</EditText>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/tx2"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="@string/ed2"
    android:inputType="textCapCharacters|textAutoCorrect"
    android:ems="10" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView4"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/tx3"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText3"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="@string/ed3"
    android:inputType="textCapCharacters|textAutoCorrect"
    android:ems="10" />

<RadioGroup
    android:id="@+id/radioGroup1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radio1"
        android:layout_width="304dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:checked="true"
        android:text="@string/radioTX1" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radio2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/radioTX2" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radio3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/radioTX3" />
</RadioGroup>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:onClick="doSomething"
    android:text="@string/bt1" />
```

Comment: You'll have to provide your layout code, and a screenshot of the issue never hurts.

Answer (score 3):

You should make sure to make your layouts as flexible as possible. This includes using things like RelativeLayouts, and things like [layout_weight](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.LayoutParams.html#attr_android%3alayout_weight). You can also preview your layouts in the android layout editor by changing the screen size ... this ensures that it will behave as expected on smaller (or larger) screen sizes.

The mindset should be similar to web developers making responsive layouts. Some great documentation/guidance from Google can be found here:
http://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes.html

Comment: I've checked the previews. It fill the whole screen like it should from 3-4" displays, cuts some elements at 2.7", and at 7"+ it fills less than half a screen. How I can change the layout to be the same for all screen sizes?

Comment: as @eric mentioned in the comments, it's kind of hard to give you guidance without any code or layouts to reference. But as I mentioned (and as mentioned in the multiscreen google guidance I linked above) ... you have to use layout elements that will resize (or layout) accordingly to the screen.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if there isn't enough space to show all this on a small screen, then you should put this all these inside a ScrollView so that the user can scroll the page. Android won't add a ScrollView automatically for you.

You can do this for all sizes of screen (shouldn't hurt anyone even if they have a bigger screen) or only for the smaller screens.